# EditText onEditorAction

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy realizando una aplicación donde ingreso el código de los usuarios por medio de un escaner manual, necesito disparar un evento justo cuando el `EditText` recibe los datos del código de barras.

Desactive la opción de recibir datos por medio del teclado por lo que este no se visualiza.

Este es mi codigo **java**.

```
edtEmployeeID.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), edtEmployeeID.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Aunque no eh ingresado a el utilizando el escaner.

En **xml**

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtEmployeeID"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/code"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecundaryText"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues al final e optado por cambiar de método y usar `addTextChangedListener()` para detectar un cambio dentro del `EditText`, y ha funcionado justo como quería.

```
 edtEmployeeID.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (s.toString().contains("\n")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), edtEmployeeID.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edtEmployeeID.setText("");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Esta es la mejor forma, usando addTextChangedListener()!